# Update some columns of a record if that record is being inserted during a BulkInsert

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert

Table on DB:

TABLE ALBUM
- ID_ON_DISCOGS (unique)
- ARTIST_ID
- LABEL_ID

I have to bulk insert records into this table.

The problem is that sometimes it could happen that the bulk insert tries to insert a record with a ID_ON_DISCOGS that is already present.

In that case I'd like to update the ARTIST_ID or the LABEL_ID fields with the new values.

Example:

ALBUM RECORD already in DB:

```
 |ID_ON_DISCOGS | ARTIST_ID | LABEL_ID|
 :------------------------------------:
 |123           | 345       | null    |
 :------------------------------------:
```

ALBUM RECORD I try to insert:

```
 |ID_ON_DISCOGS | ARTIST_ID | LABEL_ID|
 :------------------------------------:
 |123           | null       | 567    |
 :------------------------------------:
```

result record I'd like to achieve:

```
 |ID_ON_DISCOGS | ARTIST_ID | LABEL_ID|
 :------------------------------------:
 |123           | 345        | 567    |
 :------------------------------------:
```

Possibly a solution that could fit in a content provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would perform the bulk insert first.  Once it has completed, I would perform an update statement.  Maybe try updating with a CTE?  See mobsites answer for example: [SQL UPDATE row Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969517/sql-update-row-number)

Answer (score -1):

This will update all records that have a matching ID_ON_DISCOGS.

```
 REPLACE INTO ALBUM
(ID_ON_DISCOGS, ARTIST_ID, LABEL_ID)
SELECT src.ID_ON_DISCOGS, src.ARTIST_ID, src.LABEL_ID
FROM ImportTable src
INNER JOIN ALBUM dest
ON src.ID_ON_DISCOGS = dest.ID_ON_DISCOGS
```

The next query will then insert the remaining records not in the table already.

```
INSERT INTO ALBUM
SELECT imp.ID_ON_DISCOGS
       ,imp.ARTIST_ID
       ,imp.LABEL_ID
FROM ImportTable imp
WHERE imp.ID_ON_DISCOGS NOT IN (SELECT ID_ON_DISCOGS FROM ALBUM)
```

Comment: Did not notice it was SQLLite. I updated it to use replace instead.

Comment: This query does not take non-NULL values from the old row.